# DBUtils Column 'id' not found Java JDBC

Tags: java, база-данных, jdbc

Использую DBUtils для работы с базой.
Имею такой запрос:

```
SELECT start, end, status FROM payments AS p WHERE p.user_id = 1;
```

Но при выполнении возникает ошибка:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found. Query: SELECT start, end, status FROM payments AS p WHERE p.id = ?; Parameters: [1]
```

При чём странно то что этот же запрос успешно выполняется в `phpMyAdmin`.

Код:

```
new QueryRunner(source).query("SELECT start, end, status FROM payments AS p WHERE p.user_id = 1", new ResultSetHandler<JSONObject>() {
            public JSONObject handle(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
                return rs;
            }
        }, id);
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: а если убрать параметр `id`, то ошибка уйдет?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman так его там нет.

Comment: а в последней строчке кода разве не параметр?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman параметр. но мне же он нужен.